# BGE Action Actuator and Motion Actuator

Tags: game-engine

I'm making a 3D Pacman game using BGE.
I have an action actuator that plays the Pacman mouth animation.
That works, but when I add the Motion Actuator for the player to rotate the character, everything moves fine, except the mouth.
If I remove the action actuator, the whole character rotates, but the mouth is always closed.

[image: Game Logic]
[Here's the link to the .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz44ARiKq740ZDJXYy10Y3JRQk0/view?usp=sharing)

I tried looking for similar problems online for about 2 or 3 hours and found nothing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer that fits my needs.
I made this Python script that **stops the action actuator**, **rotates** to the desired position and **then plays the animation again**.
I also added an **always** sensor to keep pacman moving on the direction defined by the "direcao" property.

```
from bge import logic
import math
controller = logic.getCurrentController()
own = controller.owner

name = "AnimaBocaAcao"
start = 1.0
end = 24.0
layer = 0
priority = 1
blendin = 1.0
mode = logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_LOOP
layerWeight = 0.0
ipoFlags = 0
speed = 1.0



sensors = own.sensors

if own["direcao"] == "dir":
    own.applyMovement([0,0.02,0])
elif own["direcao"] == "esq":
    own.applyMovement([0,-0.02,0])
elif own["direcao"] == "cima":
    own.applyMovement([-0.02,0,0])
else:
    own.applyMovement([0.02,0,0])

if sensors["W"].positive:
    currentOrientation = [0, 0, math.radians(90)]
    own.stopAction()
    own["direcao"] = "cima"
if sensors["S"].positive:
    currentOrientation = [0, 0, math.radians(270)]
    own.stopAction()
    own["direcao"] = "baixo"
if sensors["A"].positive:
    currentOrientation = [0, 0, math.radians(180)]
    own.stopAction()
    own["direcao"] = "esq"
if sensors["D"].positive:
    currentOrientation = [0, 0, 0]
    own.stopAction()
    own["direcao"] = "dir"

own.localOrientation = currentOrientation
own.playAction(name, start, end, layer, priority, blendin, mode, layerWeight, ipoFlags, speed)
```

[image: Game Logic]